# In R, how to sum certain rows of a data frame with certain logic?

Tags: r, sum

Hi experienced R users,

It's kind of a simple thing. 
I want to sum `x` by `Group.1` depending on one controllable variable.

I'd like to sum `x` by grouping the first two rows when I say something like: `number <- 2`
If I say `3`, it should sum `x` of the first three rows by `Group.1`

Any idea how I might tackle this problem? Should I write a function? 
Thank y'all in advance.

```
  Group.1  Group.2      x
1       1     Eggs 230299
2       2     Eggs 263066
3       3     Eggs 266504
4       4     Eggs 177196
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `by` function.

For instance, given the following data.frame:

```
d <- data.frame(Group.1=c(1,1,2,1,3,3,1,3),Group.2=c('Eggs'),x=1:8)

> d
  Group.1 Group.2 x
1       1    Eggs 1
2       1    Eggs 2
3       2    Eggs 3
4       1    Eggs 4
5       3    Eggs 5
6       3    Eggs 6
7       1    Eggs 7
8       3    Eggs 8
```

You can do this:

```
num <- 3 # sum only the first 3 rows

# The aggregation function:
# it is called for each group receiving the 
# data.frame subset as input and returns the aggregated row
innerFunc <- function(subDf){
  # we create the aggregated row by taking the first row of the subset
  row <- head(subDf,1)
  # we set the x column in the result row to the sum of the first "num"
  # elements of the subset
  row$x <- sum(head(subDf$x,num))
  return(row)
}
# Here we call the "by" function:
# it returns an object of class "by" that is a list of the resulting
# aggregated rows; we want to convert it to a data.frame, so we call
# rbind repeatedly by using "do.call(rbind, ... )"
d2 <- do.call(rbind,by(data=d,INDICES=d$Group.1,FUN=innerFunc))

> d2
  Group.1 Group.2  x
1       1    Eggs  7
2       2    Eggs  3
3       3    Eggs 19
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I still don't understand everything you wrote there. But I believe this is what I want.

Comment: @lulumink: added some comments to make the code less obscure ;)

Answer (score 6):

If the sums you want are always cumulative, there's a function for that, `cumsum`.  It works like this.

```
> cumsum(c(1,2,3))
[1] 1 3 6
```

In this case you might want something like

```
> mysum <- cumsum(yourdata$x)
> mysum[2] # the sum of the first two rows
> mysum[3] # the sum of the first three rows
> mysum[number] # the sum of the first "number" rows
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data is in `mydata`:

```
with(mydata, sum(x[Group.1 <= 2])
```

Comment: thank you! This may be a faster way to do simple things. good to know!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum only a subset of your data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE"), c(1,2,3,4,5))
names(my_data)[1] <- "DESCRIPTION" #Change Column Name
names(my_data)[2] <- "NUMBER"      #Change Column Name

sum(subset(my_data, my_data$DESCRIPTION=="TRUE")$NUMBER)
```

You should get 6.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `Eggs` are important here ;)

```
df1 <- data.frame(Gr=seq(4),
                  x=c(230299, 263066, 266504, 177196)
                  )
```

now with `n=2` i.e. first two rows:

```
n <- 2
sum(df1[, "x"][df1[, "Gr"]<=n])
```

The expression `[df1[, "Gr"]<=n]` creates a logical vector to subset the elements in `df1[, "x"]` before `sum`ming them.

Also, it appears your `Group.1` is the same as the row no. If so this may be simpler:

```
sum(df1[, "x"][1:n])
```

or to get all at once

```
cumsum(df1[, "x"])
```