# Sum particular observations based on certain logical statements for an ID variable using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains the ZIP code, as well as 2 indicator variables denoting the race and ethnicity of the individual, as well as the count for each combination. The data can be accessed as follows:

```
Data1990 <- read.table("https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/tables/1990-2000/intercensal/st-co/stch-icen1990.txt")
names(Data1990)<-c("Year","ZIP","Age","Race","Ethnic","Count")
Data1990<-Data1990[,c(2,4:6)]
```

The data looks like this:

```
   ZIP Race Ethnic Count
1 1001    1      1   239
2 1001    2      1   203
3 1001    1      1   821
4 1001    2      1   769
5 1001    1      1  1089
6 1001    2      1   961
```

I would like to create a new dataset which contains the proportion of white non-hispanics (Race = 1 or 2 and Ethnicity=1) in that particular ZIP code. I tried getting the sum of the white non-hispanics for each zip code by using a forloop. However, this code just gives the Variable "White" a 0 for each observation.

```
zip<-unique(Data1990$ZIP)
Data1990New<-data.frame(zip,White=NA)
for(i in zip){
Data1990New[which(zip==i),]$White <- sum(Data1990[(Data1990$Race==1 |Data1990$Race==2)&Data1990$Ethnic==1&
                                      Data1990$ZIP==Data1990New$i,][,4])
}

head(Data1990New)
```

I would like to do this in a more efficient way since forloops are slow. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822153/in-r-how-to-sum-certain-rows-of-a-data-frame-with-certain-logic) is relevant but I think that my question is slightly different since I have an ID variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For loops are not slow (see [here](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)). Can you provide a small snippet of the data and the algorithm used to calculate what you're after?

Comment: I am guessing that you want to take the `sum` of 'Count' variable, because the data itself is summarised, I checked the frequency count for ZIP, Ethnic, Race, it is all the same

Comment: Yes, I want to take the sum of the 'Count' variable. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @RemyM  Okay, I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data appears to be balanced, may be we need to `filter` based on the conditions, grouped by 'ZIP' and get the `sum` of 'Count'

```
library(dplyr)
Data1990 %>% 
   filter(Ethnic == 1, Race %in% 1:2) %>% 
   group_by(ZIP) %>%
   summarise(White = sum(Count))
```

Comment: This appears to be setting each observation as 38

Comment: @RemyM Pleases check the data, it is having a balanced frequency `Data1990 %>% count(ZIP, Ethnic, Race) %>% pull(n) %>% n_distinct#
[1] 1`

Answer (score 1):

Consider calculating the *White* and then `aggregate` for proportions:

```
Data1990$White <- with(Data1990, ifelse((Race==1 | Race==2) & Ethnicity==1, 1, 0))

agg <- do.call(data.frame, 
               aggregate(White ~ ZIP, Data1990, 
                         function(x) c(Total_All = length(x), Total_White = sum(x),
                                       White_Prop = sum(x) / length(x)))
       )
```

Note: Every zip code renders same size and white totals. Check original data.